# Joomla - Help to create templates

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am starting to develop a frontend of a Joomla template.

Does anyone have a link to download or a db/dump or something with all components and categories activated?

Basically it's a demo dump to help me to show all components needed on any template.

Or... do I need to put it by hand?

Comment: Why don't you take a copy of the default Joomla template and start modifying it?

Comment: But make a copy first and modify that. Copy is supported in the tempalte manager.

Comment: Here is a tutorial to create joomla template from scratch http://a2znotes.blogspot.in/2014/08/create-joomla-template-from-scratch_28.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/create-template
I recommend you to use XAMPP and phpMyAdmin from it for your Joomla! start-up site - pretty easy and fast.

Comment: Really thanks for this tutorial! Actually i am using nginx on front service and apache2 on background service =). So, i trying to reinstall all process and found a option that copy a "fake" content inside the template, this help me a lot!

Comment: I am really glad this helped you (: I have not heard about nginx, interesting, now I am going to read about it! Good luck with the fake content!